# generate random number not including some numbers

Tags: c#, random

Is there a way to generate a random number from a group of numbers that wont include some numbers? For example - random number from 20-50 not including 25,27,34.

Comment: Can you please show minimal but complete program demonstrating your problem?

Comment: 1) Generate an array of "allowed" items. 2) Pick a random item. This algorithm seems for me to be worse than the previous one, if there are too little "unallowed" items, but better if there are too many of them.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: your idea is very good from a statistical perspective. Put as an answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ implementation of @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev comment:

```
var allowed = Enumerable.Range(20, 31).Except(new int[] { 25, 27, 34 });

Random rand = new Random();

int randomNum = allowed.ElementAt(rand.Next(0, allowed.Count()));
```

Comment: Thank you, your mothos is very helpful.
will this method favor some numbers more than others?

Comment: @avisikirov - no, every number has exactly the same probability

Answer (score 6):

A scheme where you generate a number in the range 20 to 50 then discard the ones you don't want *will introduce statistical bias*. (You'll tend to increase the variance of the resulting distribution; particularly if your generator is linear congruential).

The best way is to generate in the range 20 - 47 (call a drawing `x` say) then make adjustments using

`if (x >= 25) ++x;`
`if (x >= 27) ++x;`
`if (x >= 34) ++x;`

Comment: I don't understand how this will avoid the numbers 25, 27 and 34.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Not sure why this would be better than discarding and regenerating though.

Comment: The theory is quite deep. But in summary, in arbitrarily missing out numbers you change the autocorrelation properties for which a generator will have already compensated. The effect is to increase the sample variance and perturb higher moments. Run some analysis to see the effect. Run a chi square test for uniformity on such a sample with the numbers transformed back to consecutive.

Comment: Interesting. Is that true for true random numbers too or only for PRNGs?

Comment: It's not true for *true* random number generators as they are Markov. Only for pseudo.

Comment: Nice and simple. Guess the downvoter doesn't understand the elegance of your solution.

Comment: They will once they have published their research paper. Tonne of bricks on its way.